# Variables inside javascript object cannot be read

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, variables

There is my orginal code:

```
$("#container").someFunction([{
     title: "Item1",
     color: "#FFFFFF"
}, {
     title: "Item2",
     color: "#000000"
}]);
```

The above code is WORKING, but once I try to change these:

```
 var items = '{'+'title: "Tokyo",'+'color: "#2C3E50"'+'}, {' + 'title: "Tokyo",'+'color: "#2C3E50"'+'}';

 $("#container").someFunction([items]);
 //or
 $("#container").someFunction(function(items){return items});
 //or
 $("#container").someFunction(items);
 //or
 $("#container").someFunction(eval("items"));
```

It doesn't work anymore.

I am wondering is there any ways to achieve this?

Comment: What are `myFunction` and `someFunction`?

Comment: You have to parse it before passing to that function

Comment: should be all someFunction, typing mistakes

Comment: I can think of no reason at all for why you would need to change a working object in to a hacked together string...? Your question serves no purpose as your original code is perfectly fine as it is.

Comment: You have an invalid JSON though. I am not sure why are you creating a string instead of an object

Comment: You might need to use `eval` for this, but it is dangerous.

Comment: I tried eval, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Could you please be more specific regarding that "someFunction"?

The variable "items" works as is:

```
 $('#container').on('click',function(){
     $(this).html(items); });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vkpfntqx/3/